# Running bash_profile commands with python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

In my bash terminal, I can run the following command:

```
$SCHRODINGER/run volume_calc.py -imae type.mae
```

and this works correctly.

I am then trying to run the same command in a python script; where I have tried the following approach:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['$SCHRODINGER/run', 'volume_calc.py', '-imae', 'type.mae'])
```

which throws the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '$SCHRODINGER/run'
```

I am confused what the issue could be, as I can run basic bash commands fine. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variable expansion is not done by default using subprocess unless you pass the `shell` argument to the `subprocess.run` call. This will pass your arguments to a shell (e.g. `bash`) which will handle the desired expansion and any other shell-like functionality.

Here's the code change necessary:

```
subprocess.run(['$SCHRODINGER/run', 'volume_calc.py', '-imae', 'type.mae'], shell=True)
```

Note that it is worth reading through the [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) for using this given in the python documentation.